# How to set core file name using c++ code?

Tags: c++, linux

How can I set the core file name using c++ code in linux ?

Linux dump core file on binary crash , is it possible to set core dump file name ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the core file name"?

Comment: sorry for my bad for me core means linux crash core file. updated the question.

Comment: It's the kernel who creates the file, so I don't think you can write any C++ code to set the file's name.

Comment: It is possible to set the core file name, but from inside the C++ code, seems little out of this world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my system (Ubuntu 10.04 with kernel 2.6.32), `man core` gives no indication that the naming can be chosen on a process-by-process basis. In can, however, be changed system-wide by modifying `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`:

> By  default,  a core dump file is named core, but the
>   `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file (since Linux 2.6 and 2.4.21) can 
>   be set to define a template that is used to name core dump files.  The
>   template can contain % specifiers which  are  sub‐    stituted by the
>   following values when a core file is created:
>
> ```
>    %%  a single % character
>    %p  PID of dumped process
>    %u  (numeric) real UID of dumped process
>    %g  (numeric) real GID of dumped process
>    %s  number of signal causing dump
>    %t  time of dump, expressed as seconds since the Epoch (00:00h, 1 Jan 1970, UTC)
>    %h  hostname (same as nodename returned by uname(2))
>    %e  executable filename (without path prefix)
>    %c  core file size soft resource limit of crashing process (since Linux 2.6.24)
> ```
>
> A  single  `%`  at  the end of the template is dropped from the core
>   filename, as is the combination of a `%` followed by any    character
>   other than those listed above.  All other characters in the template
>   become a literal part of  the  core  filename.   The  template 
>   may  include `'/'` characters, which are interpreted as delimiters for
>   directory names.  The maximum    size of the resulting core filename
>   is 128 bytes (64 bytes in kernels before 2.6.19).  The default value
>   in this file  is    "core".   For  backward  compatibility,  if 
>   `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`  does  not  include  `"%p"`  and 
>   `/proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid` (see below) is non-zero, then `.PID`
>   will be appended to the core filename.

Comment: @VivekGoel valgrind somehow manages to name its cores "vgcore.<pid>" regardless of  th core pattern sysctl.

Comment: @fstd valgrind generates a core-file by itself. See e.g. https://github.com/tklengyel/valgrind/blob/971c165fc4335bf04bedf58e0800a12776fce408/coregrind/m_coredump/coredump-elf.c

Answer (score 5):

I believe [this page](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/coredump.htm) describes what you're looking for, generally. What you can do is set the way core files are named by changing a magic entry in the `proc` filesystem:

```
echo "pattern" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

where *pattern* is a `printf`-like pattern string, documented on the linked page. Doing this from C++ would just entail opening and writing to that file using normal mechanisms. However, you must be root to be able to write to 'core_pattern'.